# If "Imbue Familiar with Spell Ability" is cast on a familiar, does the Share Spells ability allow its spell to be shared with the original caster?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, familiars

If a wizard/sorcerer employs the spell "Imbue Familiar with Spell Ability", transfers spells on his familiar and has then his familiar cast a spell (e.g. Invisibility) on him, can his familiar share that spell (become invisible as well)?

In other words: does the Share Spell ability of the familiar still work although it is not the master that is casting the spell?

> Share Spells
>
> At the master’s option, he may have any spell ... he casts on himself also affect his familiar.

I tend to say ´no´, but I´m not quite sure. One could argue that although the familiar functions as the caster it´s still the master´s spell that´s being cast and the master´s caster level that is being applied.

> ... The transferred spell's variable characteristics (range, duration, area, and so on) function according to your level. ... (Spell description "Imbue Familiar with Spell Ability")

So, in a way, the master casts the spell (Invisibility in this case) - via his familiar - on himself.
If you see it like this the familiar should then be able to share that spell.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***imbue familiar with spell ability*** [univ] (*Spell Compendium* 120), in part, says, "This spell allows you to transfer a number of your spells *and the ability to cast them* into your familiar" (emphasis mine).

The familiar's supernatural ability [**share spells**](http://dndsrd.net/wizard.html#familiar-share-spells) says, in part, "At the master’s option, he may have any spell (but not any spell-like ability) he casts on himself also affect his familiar" (*Player's Handbook* 53). However, the inverse isn't true: It *doesn't* say that at the familiar's option, it may have any spell it casts on itself also affect its master!

Thus, when the familiar gains the ability to cast spells from the *imbue* spell, even though the "transferred spell’s variable characteristics (range, duration, area, and so on) function according to [the master's] level" (*SpC* 120), the spell still won't actually be *cast* by the master but by the familiar, therefore it can't be shared by the familiar with the master using the familiar's share spells ability.